# How do I convert from human terms back to numbers in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are helpers in Ruby on Rails to convert numbers to human terms, like 1024KB can be converted to 1MB. Is there a method to  reverse it?

I want to convert 6.3K to 6300, 6.3L 6300000, etc.

Comment: Also, NumberHelper in Rails doesn't convert "1024KB" to "1MB", it takes a number (as 1048576, for example), not a string expression.

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Alchemy gem](https://github.com/toastyapps/alchemist/).

```
require 'alchemy'
6.3.kg.to.g
#=> 6300.0
```